# gcc dereferencing pointer to incomplete type with c11

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, reference, c11

I am noob with c. I have error during compilation with --std=c11 and

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
```

that is

```
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

It does not appear with not --std=c11 and define.
My code is like:

```
struct icmp* icmp;
char send_buffer[BSIZE];
...
icmp = (struct icmp *) send_buffer;
icmp->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
```

and the error is:

```
icmp.c: In function ‘prepare_send_icmp’:
icmp.c:41:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  icmp->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
```

It does not appear with no gcc flag --std=c11
how to repair it?

Comment: are you sure your `struct icmp` is visible from the file? did you miss a header or somethin'?

Comment: Did you include the definition for `struct icmp` — I think `#include netinet/ip_icmp.h` might fix it.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with C11 standard vs. older standards. Read about "incomplete types" as the error suggests pretty clearly.

Comment: Ok, i see, the problem is #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600, but how can I make it work with that define?

Comment: @Olaf: Using an `_` for a preprocessor name isn't critical; it'll resolve to the `600` by the time the compiler/linker see the code.

Comment: How should we see that? Context missing. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: @Olaf: `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is not just a custom macro. It's  feature test macro defined by POSIX.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oh, ok! Didn't know that. So, I retreat full of shame :-). Was just not clear from the context given. But your statement that "`_` for a preprocessor name ..." is still wrong if read as-is.

Comment: Reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html section 2.2.1.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thank you. Hope I will not forget about this (I'm actually not working with POSIX, right now)

Answer (score 1):

The answer
to your question is to #define _GNU_SOURCE.